# Radix sort with a vector of vectors in C++ crashes

Tags: c++, vector, radix-sort

I'm trying to write a radix sort that uses a vector of random numbers and a vector of vectors for the bins.

Here's the code, the error is somewhere in the gather and/or distribute functions - any help would be appreciated, I'm just not spotting it.  It's not giving me an error mesage, just crashing. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

void distribute(vector<int> & myList, vector< vector<int> > & bins, int place);
void gather(vector<int> & myList, vector< vector<int> > & bins);
int getNumDigits(vector<int> myList);


int main(){
    int place = 1;
    vector<int> myList(20);
    vector< vector<int>  > bins;


    //initialize the vector
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){

        myList[i] = rand() % 300;
    }

    //get mumber of digits of largest

    place = getNumDigits(myList);

    cout << "Unsorted list: " << endl ;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){

        cout << myList[i] << " ";
    }

    distribute(myList, bins, place);
    gather(myList, bins);

cout << endl << "Sorted once " ;

for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){

 cout << myList[i] << " ";
 }

system("pause");
return 0;

}//end main

void distribute(vector<int> & myList, vector< vector<int> > & bins, int place){


bins.clear();

int modder = place * 10;


for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){

    bins[(myList[i]) % modder].push_back(myList[i]);

    }//endfor  (myList[i]) % modder



}//end distribute


void gather(vector<int> & myList, vector< vector<int> > & bins){

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < bins[i].size(); j++){

         myList.push_back(bins[i][j]);

     }//end inner
 }//end outer

 }

int getNumDigits(vector<int> myList){

 int place = 0;
 int biggest = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){

     if (myList[i] > biggest)
         biggest = myList[i];

     }

 while (biggest > 0){
     place++;
     biggest = biggest / 10;
     }

 return place;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for (int j = 0; j < bins[i].size(); i++)` does not look right.

I suppose you meant `j++`, not `i++`.

Comment: Yeah, fixed that, still crashes though.  I think it's something in this line:  bins[(myList[i]) % modder].push_back(myList[i]);

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough space in your `bins` vector in `distribute`. Change its beginning to this:

```
bins.clear();

int modder = place * 10;

bins.resize(modder);
```

A vector will automatically resize while adding items to it, but you can't access an item beyond the vector size without resizing it before.

Comment: Sweet, that took care of the crashing.  Thank you so much.